# usb_cam + Microsoft Lifecam Studio Rendering Issues

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the Microsoft Lifecam up and running in ROS using the usb_cam node. It is able to open the camera fine and display and image but the image is extremely bright (see the image at the bottom of the post) and makes it almost impossible to detect anything in the image when there is natural sunlight around. The usb_cam node is also outputting the following error to the console when I try to use the camera:

```
[swscaler @ 0x1851a20] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv422p to rgb24.
```

I am not sure if this is part of the problem of the web camera displaying improperly or not but if you could help with either of these issues it would be greatly appreciated!

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59445/usb_cam-+-microsoft-lifecam-studio-rendering-issues/) by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try `guvcview` to control such camera parameters as exposure, brightness etc. I am not sure that all Microsoft Lifecams support UVC, but at least some of them are reported to do so.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0